# sum of past and future samples at each index in a list or array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I would like know is there any inbuilt python modules to calculate the average of current value, one past and one future value at every index in a list. (if past samples are not available, use only the future samples and vice versa)

If not, what is the efficient way to do that?

at index a(i), I need average(a(i-1), a(i), a(i+1))

for input:

```
[3, 5, 1, 6, 7]
```

I should get

```
[4, 3, 4, 4.6, 6.5]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean past and future values? So the average of every value except the one at the current index?  Do you mean the average of a number and its neighbors?

Comment: Not exactly. Lets say current index is a(i), then in the new list the index(a(i)) should contain the average(a(i-1), a(i), a(i+1)).

Comment: Isn't that the average of a number and its neighbors?

Comment: yeah, you are right. But i gave a clear explanation

Comment: Is there an average for`a[0]`? Is it the average of `a[-1]`, `a[0]`, and `a[1]`?

Comment: It is average of a[-1], a[0], and a[1].

Answer (score 3):

Oh, there are many different ways. Here's another:

```
x = np.array([3,5,1,6,7])
y = np.convolve(x, np.ones((3,))/3, mode='same')

# fixing the values at the boundaries
y[0]  = np.mean(x[:2])
y[-1] = np.mean(x[-2:])
```

It uses convolution to calculate an average of each 3 neighboring elements, but it pads zeros at the boundaries, so we need a second step to fix those.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension, getting the respective slice and it's mean.

```
>>> a = [3, 5, 1, 6, 7]
>>> [a[max(0, i-1):i+2] for i in range(len(a))]
[[3, 5], [3, 5, 1], [5, 1, 6], [1, 6, 7], [6, 7]]
>>> [np.mean(a[max(0, i-1):i+2]) for i in range(len(a))]
[4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.666666666666667, 6.5]
```

(Using `max(0, i-1)` here because `[-1:2]` would be an empty slice, but there might be a nicer way to achieve the same.)

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: `max(0, i-1)` that's neat

Comment: @timgeb But it would be much neater if you could just write `[-1:2]` and get the first two elements, just like `[-2:len+3]` still gives you the last two elements. Being able to use `[-1]` for the last element is great, but Python really could be a bit smarter here IMHO.

Comment: Sure. Also, you compute that max way too many times in that oneliner. You know the result will be i-1 every time except the first call. Still neat.

Comment: @timgeb Exactly, but any other way would be even less readable. Maybe `0 if i == 0 else i-1` would be a bit faster, though (and not too terrible either).